# set a custom theme for drupal admin panel

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

```
Hello everyone, I have an admin dashboard that I want to use as the main theme of the admin dashboard in Drupal.
How can this be done?
```

I did a lot of work on this including editing the default Drupal template but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Have you selected your theme as an admin theme in appearance in drupal ?

[admin theme selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WDGO.png)

If not then select from here.